# how to get search result using search key if search key matches any of first letter of sentence

Tags: javascript, search, data-structures

Thanks in advance

I have a requirement where I need to filter a list in `javascript` using the search key. The algorithm should work as following.

**If I have the following items in list**

1. Include your goal passion.
2. Describe in detail development.
3. Make you aim perfect with spirit.

If my search key is **p** it should get me items whose first word match **p**.
Here it should bring up **(1)** and **(3)**
It should not bring *(2)* even though it had ****p**** in development

Comment: Sounds like a primo use case for a regular expression using a _word boundary_ assertion, I’d say. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Assertions#Boundary-type_assertions

Answer (score 0):

regular express will work, like CBroe mentioned.

simple option is startsWith("p") or str.includes(" p");

```
const match = (needle, stack): boolean => stack.startsWith(` ${needle}`) || str.includes(" needle");
```

Note: this is relates to the described scenario.